# RemoteControlClient Ratings On Lockscreen

Tags: android, audio, lockscreen

In 4.4 Ratings were added to the RemoteControlClient.  In order to use them, you have to add the flag, add the existing Rating type, and register for the edit metadata listener.  The only two uses for the RCC at this time seem to be for the lockscreen and bluetooth.  I am pretty sure AVRCP does not support ratings, so I was assuming that this was added to the framework so that ratings can be changed from the lockscreen.

I tried adding support, and nothing seemed to have changed at all.  My question is this: did I just do something wrong, or is there no actual use of the ratings system yet?  I know that support was also added for custom controllers, so I understand if it was just added to the client in order to support people's custom controllers.  I just want to know if I should continue looking for what I am doing wrong in the code, or if there is no way to get ratings to show up on the lockscreen.

PS: I also already tried every variation of Ratings that was listed in the documentation.